# How to fill out Canada T5 dividends to US 1040 form?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, canada, dividends

I have T5 from Canada, box 24 call actual amount of eligible dividends .
box 25 call taxable amount of eligible dividends, box 26 call dividends tax credit for eligible dividends, box 18 call capital gains dividends. How do I report 1040 form ?  Can I use 1099-DIV form?  what number can fill 1a, 1b.....

Comment: It would help if you could explain more about why you have a Canadian T5 form if you are filing US taxes.  It's possible that you should be filing Canadian taxes for the T5 form.  Or it's possible that you should ask someone to send you a 1099 form to replace the T5 form.